# How to sort out list by datetime in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to angular2 and I'm trying to sort out my food order list by collection time datestamp coming from the database.

let say the order object is below and in my template I want to sort it with earliest `collectiontime` in the example below it would be `id: 2454`

```
var awaitingPicking = [
  {
   "id": "2452",
   "OrderLineGroups": [
     {
       "CollectionDetails": {
         "CollectionFrom": "2017-03-21T11:00:00.317"
       }
     }
   ]
  },
{
   "id": "2454",
   "OrderLineGroups": [
     {
       "CollectionDetails": {
         "CollectionFrom": "2017-03-21T11:00:00.317"
       }
     }
   ]
  }
 ]
```

I tried using this example but it didn't sort out the list by `CollectionFrom`

http://plnkr.co/edit/DU6pxr?p=preview

Here's my example using the above plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/TYXh2iCDseJNnT0DwKA7?p=preview

Expected result should be like --

```
- 2454 2017-03-21T11:00:00.317 // this has an early collection at (11:00 am)
- 2452 2017-03-21T11:40:00.317
```